# Interactive User Dictionary Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

What I'm trying to do is create a dictionary in python using a JSON file. I want to be able to use user input to call a word and get its meaning. I've successfully done that however I'm now stuck on the next part I want to do and have no clue where to begin.

```py
def search():
    if response == "y":
        SearchItems = input("Enter search: ")
        with open('Dictionary.json') as data: 
            term_data = json.load(data)
        if term_data.get(SearchItems, True):
            print("{} - {}".format(SearchItems, term_data[SearchItems]))
            new_response = input("Would you like to search the meaning of a new word? y/n: ")
            if new_response == "y":
                search()
            elif new_response == "n":
                exit()
        elif term_data.get(SearchItems,False):
            print("not a word in the dictionary or invalid value entered.")
            newWord ="would you like to find similar words?"
            print(newWord)
    elif response == "n":
        print("Okay Goodbye")
    else:
        exit()

response = input("Would you like to Search for a word, y/n? :  ")
search()
```

^ That is my code I've written. What I want to do now is if the value entered is not apart of my dictionary I want an error message to be printed, then to ask the user if they want to find similar words in my created dictionary. I don't know where to start on that yet and the code I have here does the first part how I want it too but if incorrect word is entered, the program just breaks and doesn't print an error message, so I am quite stuck. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: The branch `elif term_data.get(SearchItems, False)` will never work -- this is unreachable code. You have misunderstood how `dict.get()` works. The second argument is what gets returned if the key isn't found in the dictionary. If you return `False` when the term isn't in the dictionary then the `if` statement will fail. Similarly, `if term_data.get(SearchItems, True)` *will still be triggered* even if the search term is *not* in the dictionary, because you are returning `True` in that case.

Comment: Your logic should be `definition = term_data.get(SearchItems)` and then `if definition; # do stuff; else: # print error message, etc`

Comment: This is too broad of a question. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this helps and what do you think about it please. :)

```
import json


with open("Dictionary.json") as data: 
    term_data = json.load(data)


def search_items():
    """Function to search for word meanings and print information the user
    """

    search_items = input("Enter search: ")
    
    try:
         term_data[search_items]

    except KeyError:
        print(
            f"{search_items} not found in the dictionary."
        )

        ask_user_to_continue_search()

    else:
        print("{} - {}".format(search_items, term_data[search_items]))

        ask_user_to_continue_search()


def ask_user_to_continue_search():
    """Function asks the user if wants to continue searching for the meaning
    of words
    """

    response = input(
        "Would you like to search the meaning of a new word? y/n: "
    )

    if response is not "y":
        exit()

    search_items()


search_items()
```